Using Plex through a VPN only works for HTTPS but not the iOS apps
I have an OpenVPN server running on my NAS. Also on that NAS is Plex media server.
When my phone is on the same network as my NAS, I can use the Plex iOS apps fine.
When I am not on my home network, I can connect to the VPN and using Safari, access Plex with my local URL (i.e. https://192.168.1.10:32400)
However, the Plex iOS apps do not work. They connect, but no music streams.
Why should the VPN permit me to access Plex via https when on the VPN but not via the apps?

Evidently I need to "Enable remote access" on the settings of the Plex Media Server.
This is supposed to set up port forwarding but I deliberately am not allowing that and don't want port forwarding - the whole point here is to use the VPN to connect and NOT port forwarding.
However, what does seem to matter is that I "manually select the public port" to 32400, the same as the local port. This is communicated to some global Plex server which, I assume, is relayed to the iOS app when I sign in. Then, I assume further, that the local apps are now using the right port for the local LAN IP address which is accessible once I'm on my VPN.
